# using a for loop to identify html .classes (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, for-loop

I'm using simplepie to pull in two rss feeds. Using a PHP `foreach` loop, I then `echo` the information each feed post contains in the class `.story_overview` and adding a `.pin` class for each article. I'm using jQuery within the PHP `foreach` to `hide.story_overview` and add a unique identifying number to the end of the `.story_overview` and respective `.pin` class and this is working:

```
<script>
    $('.story_overview').hide();
    $('.pin').attr('class','pin' + i);
    $('.story_overview').attr('class','story_overview' + i);   
    i++;
</script>
```

I'm trying to reach the desired outcome of hovering over a `.pin` revealing the respective `.story_overview` (*so `.pin1` would reveal `.story_overview1`*). I'm currently trying to do this with a JavaScript `for` loop but it refuses to work:

```
<script>
    for (x = 0; x <= i; x++){
        $('.pin'+ x.toString()).mouseover(function(){
            $('.story_overview' + x.toString()).show();
        });

        $('.pin'+ x.toString()).mouseout(function(){
            $('.story_overview' + x.toString()).hide();
        }); 
    };
</script>
```

I have tested all the jQuery commands by trying the same code but with the identifying numbers at the end of the class names (*rather than `x.toString`*) and placing the code outside of the `for` loop, and that all works.

Any help what so ever would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your `i` setted? and don't make for loop to bind event. use class instead.

Comment: Bad idea!!! Instead use a common class name to bind the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
  $('.pin').mouseover(function(){
            $('.story_overview').eq($(this).index()).show();
   }).mouseout(function(){
            $('.story_overview').eq($(this).index()).hide();
   });
```

You can achieve the desired output by using the `.eq()` method with `.index()` to get the index of the hovered element.

Or you might like this:

```
  $('.pin').mouseover(function(){
            $('.story_overview'+$(this).index()).show();
   }).mouseout(function(){
            $('.story_overview'+$(this).index()).hide();
   });
```